# How do I find the number of ordered group possible as in a sublist from a super list in python?

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have a smaller list `A = [1,2,3]` and larger list `B = [1,2,3,1,1,2,2,3,2,3]`.
**B** has no other elements except **A**'s but elements order is not maintained.

I want to find how many times **A** appears in **B** preserving **A**'s order. For this example **A** appears 3 times in **B**. I could solve this for two elements, like `[1,2]` comes 2 times in `[1,1,2,2,1,1]`. In other words, I want to find how many ordered group such **A** is possible from the larger list as **B**.

Comment: What's your solution for two elements that doesn't scale for 3?

Comment: I hardcoded for two elements sublist but seems I need to do it for arbitrary length. I basically did it using 2 nested for loops. But as sublist length may get longer, my approach does not scale up.

Comment: Ok, another question is, is it about "how many times A occures in B", or "how many As can be build from elements of B"?

Comment: How does *A* appear 3 times in *B*?  I see only one occurrence.

Comment: If `A = [1,2,3]` and larger list `B = [1,2,3,1,1,2,2,3,2,3]`, then I only see a single occurrence of `A` in `B`, i.e., the first three elements of `B`. You wrote "I want to find how many times A appears in B preserving A's order.". That statement gives only one occurrence

Comment: We're not clear on the specifications of what you want to do.  The elements `[1, 2]` appear only once in `[1, 1, 2, 2]` -- if they have to be in order and contiguous.  If they do not have to be contiguous, then `[1, 2]` appears four different ways in `[1, 1, 2, 2]`, pairing each `1` with a `2` that comes later.  If you have some elimination method that skips list positions, then you have to describe that mechanism to define your problem.  You'll also need to post your present solution, I think.

Comment: I am only looking for the ordered group possible for example as in **A**  = [1,2] from **B** =[1,1,1,2,2]. Like for the first occurrence of "1" in **B** we have a "2", then for the second "1", we have another "2", but no "2" is found for the third "1". My count is 2 here for the sublist [1,2]. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: it is precisely, how many As can be build from elements of B, as they come in the same order of A. @slam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understood, you want to count how many times all the elements of **A** are repeated in order in **B**, even if there are other elements inbetween.

If that's the case, you can use:

```
A = [1,2,3]

B = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,1,1,2,2,3,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]

counters = [0 for _ in A] # initialize a list with the same number of values of A, but all at 0


for x in B: # for each element in B
    for n in range(len(A)): # for all the indexes in A
        if x == A[n]: # if the element in B is present in A
            if n == 0 or (counters[n] < counters[n-1]):
            # if n == 0, is the first element of A: we know it's a start of a possible match
            # if the previous number in index is higher of the current number, means that we are looking for the match to continue
                counters[n] += 1 # add 1 to the current number
                break

print counters[-1] # the last number of the counters represent the times that you reached the end of a match
```

Comment: If you need a better explanation on a step, just ask

Comment: your solution is just what I needed and self-explanatory. Thank you very much.

Comment: @RubelAhmed Nice! if you need some more help just ask, otherwise you can accept the answer!

Comment: This approach works but quickly becomes inefficient as the size of `A` grows larger. Check the benchmarks if you're interested in efficiency: https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/YBH

Comment: @blhsing yes, your solution is better structured

Answer (score 1):

An efficient approach is to build a dict of queues of indices for each item in `B`, then cycle through items in `A` to look for the next item in the dict whose index is greater than the index of the last found item by keeping dequeueing until such an index is found or break the loop if any queue is exhausted, with each completed cycle incrementing the count by 1:

```
from collections import deque
index = {}
for i, n in enumerate(B):
    index.setdefault(n, deque()).append(i)
count = 0
while True:
    last = -1
    try:
        for n in A:
            while True:
                i = index[n].popleft()
                if i > last:
                    last = i
                    break
    except (IndexError, KeyError):
        break
    count += 1
```

`count` becomes:

```
3
```